# Find min value (parameters estmation) based on recurrence equations

Tags: r, recurrence

Sorry for trivial question, but I`m not a programmer. Do I  transformed the following tasks in the form of R function OK?

I have recurrence equations, e.g.(p1_par,...,p4_par-parameters to find):

```
z1[i+1]= z1[i]+p1_par*p2_par
z12[i+1]= z12[i]+(p1_par*z1[i]-p3_par*z1z2[i]-p4_par)*p2_par
z1z2[i+1]=z1z2[i]+(-p3_par*z12[i]-p4_par*z1z2[i])*p2_par
i=1,...,5
```

with the initial conditions for i=0:

```
z1_0=1.23
z12_0=1
z1z2_0=0
and t=6, y=c(0.1,0.06,0.08,0.04,0.05,0.01)
```

I want to find parameters based on min value of function e.g. like this:

```
(-2*p1_par*z1[i]-z12[i]+y[i+1]^2+2*p3_par*z1z2[i]+2*p4_par*z1z3[i])^2
```

I try to build the function in R like:

```
function1=function(p1_par,p2_par,p3_par,p4_par,y,t){
ep=1
summa=0
result=rep(1,t)
for(i in 1:t){  
z1_0=1.23
z12_0=1
z1z2_0=0
z1[1]=z1_0+p1_par*p2_par
z12[1]=z12_0+(p1_par*z1_0-*p3_par*z1z2_0-*p4_par)*p2_par
z1z2[1]=z1z2_0+(-p3_par*z12_0-p4_par*z1z2_0)*p2_par
z1[i+1]= z1[i]+p1_par*p2_par
z12[i+1]= z12[i]+p1_par*z1[i]-p3_par*z1z2[i]-p4_par)*p2_par
z1z2[i+1]=z1z2[i]+(-p3_par*z12[i]-p4_par*z1z2[i])*p2_par
if(i==1) {
result[ep]=(-2*p1_par*z1_0-z12_0+y[i+1]^2+2*p3_par*z1z2_0+2*p4_par*z1z3_0)^2
} else {
result[ep]=(-2*p1_par*z1[i]-z12[i]+y[i+1]^2+2*p3_par*z1z2[i]+2*p4_par*z1z3[i])^2
}
summa<<-summa+result[ep]
ep=ep+1
}
return(result)
}
```

Do I transformed task of the R function correct? Results from other softwares (like Math) differs. Thanks in advance for help.
PPS

Comment: In reference to your setup equations: The indexing in R is 1 based, so any code that uses [0] will fail. In reference to your loop, one would normally do the initialization outside the loop and then iterate from 2, although your way is not necessarily an error. If you have a correct answer for comparison you should offer it. I don't see any effort on your part to find any sort of minimum. Cannot use two `return` calls in a function. Well, you can, but you will only get values from the first one. Return a list instead.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Mea culpa, correct form above. Optimization step is the next. At this moment important thing is the correct form of function: if I give appropriate values of the parameters, it should give the correct value, but does not.... PPS